# How to get freebase image license?

Tags: image, licensing, freebase

[Here](http://www.freebase.com/policies/attribution) to the left it says that some freebase images are Specifically Licensed and to use them I have to  attribute the original creator, link to the correct license, and link to the Freebase image page. The problem is, how do I get the license type of a specific image?

I get the images like they say [here](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Image_Service) and I get other freebase info from there data dumps.

I can get most of the image info from the data dump by following [this](http://schemas.freebaseapps.com/type?id=/common/image) schema, but I dont now how to get the license. And some images requires that I link to the license.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the Topic API or MQL will give you the information that you seek.

For example, if you're fetching your image with

```
https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/m/0290v28
```

the equivalent Topic API URL is

```
https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/0290v28
```

which will have the license, provenance, and attribution information.

Comment: Thanks. From that I managed to find it in the data dump. Not sure why I did not manage to find that it was under "/common/licensed_object", it was almost right in front of me.